# How to move to next button if first one is disabled in Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHgHK.png)I have 5 buttons with text "x", My Selenium script below only attempts to access the first which is disabled and moves on to another line of script written to do something else. All the x's have the same ID's and elements so I cannot call them separately.

How do I get my Selenium Java to check all 5 buttons before moving on to other task?

Selenium code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.aui-button.aui-button-link.aui-restfultable-delete.aui-restfultable-delete-small")).click();
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="aui-button aui-button-link aui-restfultable-delete aui-restfultable-delete-small" aria-disabled="true" original-title="Disabled because this request type is used for requests created from the email channel" resolved="">×</a>
```

You can see an example in the attached screenshot. The first x is disabled and I want my Selenium code to move to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :not([disabled]) property in your css selector to get all button that are not disabled.

for your problem use below css selector,

```
a.aui-button.aui-button-link.aui-restfultable-delete.aui-restfultable-delete-small:not([disabled])
```

Comment: it is still going to the first disable button x :(.

Comment: Sure, I have added the HTML code in my question. All 5 x buttons are below each other and refer to same code. You will notice that this one has aria-disabled="true" but they all have same class.

Comment: you can try using below css 
    `a.aui-button.aui-button-link.aui-restfultable-delete.aui-restfultable-delete-small[aria-disabled='false']`

Comment: where do you want me to use this? in Selenium webdriver?

Comment: Yeah. driver.findElement (By.cssSelector("a.aui-button.aui-button-link.aui-restfultable-delete.aui-restfultable-delete-small [aria-disabled='false']"))

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code:

```
// Selecting all the elements
List<WebElement> allele = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[text()='x']"));

// Looping through the elements using for-each loop
for(WebElement eachEle : allele) {
    // Checking whether the element is enabled or not
    if(eachEle.isEnabled()) {
        eachEle.click();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its displaying an error on "List" - the type list is not generic, it cannot be parameterized with arguments <WebElement> :(

Comment: I imported java.util.list and it is clicking on the x that is enabled finally but not moving down to another x? There a 2 in total

Comment: Can you please paste the complete html code of all the 'x' in the code so that we can find the way to store all the x's in the List.

Comment: I have edited my answer by replacing the cssSelector with xpath. Please try the same and let me know if you face challenges still

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following code which will check for aria-disabled attribute and according to that it will click on element:

```
List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.id("your id"));
      for (int i = 0; i < ele.size(); i++) {
                    if (ele.get(i).getAttribute("aria-disabled") != "true") {
                        ele.get(i).click();
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Its displaying an error on "List" - the type list is not generic, it cannot be parameterized with arguments <WebElement> :( I am using Eclipse

Comment: Have you imported java.util.List? And which version of java and eclipse are you using?Wrong import of list  causes this issue often